# SerialPort.list() return empty array

Tags: node.js, electron, node-serialport

Does anyone have any idea why this (below) code return an empty array on windows ?

```
const SerialPort = require('serialport')

SerialPort.list()
  .then((ports) => {
    console.log(ports, "s")
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err, "e"))
```

Tech Stack:
Node: v14
Electron: v12
serialport: v9

Comment: Is the serial adapter recgonzied in the device manager? All drivers installed?

Comment: There is nothing about serial adaptor in documentation. Isn't this package supposed to be used directly using require ?

Comment: Yes, but you need a serial adapter to work with. What are you suppost to do with the pacakge when you have no serial adapter/device? https://superuser.com/a/1412122/952138 & https://superuser.com/a/835853/952138

Comment: The thing I want is simply a list of ports on a device

Comment: If there is no port. there is no list. Are the powershell/cmd commands returning anything?

Comment: There are ports, I physically confirm them by using usb device or something

Comment: If you dont want help, fine. Ff you want help please read all my question and answer them! What does the cmd/powershell commands return? What does the device manager say? Are all driver installed? Are they in the device manager recognized?

Comment: Okay so, I got what I was trying to do by using node-hid lib. Thanks for your time though

Comment: Good for you. But im a litle bit confused, a serial adapter is not a HID, What USB adapter are you using?

Comment: What I wanted to do is send signals to a keyboard to change its led lights. I thought I could achieve this by using this lib. and communicating through serial ports

Comment: A keyboard does not provide a serial interface. A Keyboard is a Human Interface Device, thats why you didnt get anything back from serial port.

Comment: Ohh That's why!

Comment: I have same issue with a USB-connected Zebra label printer. Is such a printer also HID & not serial device? The application I have needs a "path" of printer to be specified to give prints & uses SerialPort to connect to that path. I tried entering this path as  USB001 (the port I see in printer settings), also tried to set it to a path by enabling sharing of this printer but it does not work. Any suggestions?